# Throws "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Tags: c#, wpf, usb

I am trying to write data from serial to `USB` device to text field but it keeps throwing:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

I know that I have to do something with dispatch or something along those lines but not sure wehre to start.  I am sure it is simple but I am drawing a blank.  Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace serial_app_one
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private SerialPortProgram _serial;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _serial = new SerialPortProgram(this);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    class SerialPortProgram
    {
        // Create the serial port
        private SerialPort port;
        MainWindow _window;

        public SerialPortProgram(MainWindow window)
        {
            _window = window;
           AppendText("Incoming Data:");
            port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            // Attach a method to be called when there
            // is data waiting in the port's buffer
            port.DataReceived += new
              SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

            // Begin communications
            port.Open();    
        }      

        private void AppendText(string text)
        {                               
            _window.Dev_output.Text += string.Format("{0}{1}", text, Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private void port_DataReceived(object sender,
          SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
            AppendText(port.ReadExisting());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
private void AppendText(string text)
{
     Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
     {
        _window.Dev_output.Text += string.Format("{0}{1}", text, Environment.NewLine);
     }));
}
```

Comment: I get Error 1 'serial_app_one.SerialPortProgram' does not contain a definition for 'Dispatcher' and no extension method 'Dispatcher' accepting a first argument of type 'serial_app_one.SerialPortProgram' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Brock.Davis\Downloads\serial_app_one\serial_app_one\serial_app_one\MainWindow.xaml.cs 56 18 serial_app_one

Answer (score 1):

in your serialport class, you need to store the dispatcher of the UI thread, which is conviently the one during the constructor.  So store it away, then every time you append text you need to Invoke on that dispatcher

```
class SerialPortProgram
    {
        // Create the serial port
        private SerialPort port;
        MainWindow _window;
        private Dispatcher _dispatcher;

        public SerialPortProgram(MainWindow window)
        {
            _window = window;
            AppendText("Incoming Data:");
            port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            // Attach a method to be called when there
            // is data waiting in the port's buffer
            port.DataReceived += port_DataReceived;
            _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            // Begin communications
            port.Open();

        }



        private void AppendText(string text)
        {
            _dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
               _window.Dev_output.Text += string.Format("{0}{1}", text, Environment.NewLine);
            });
        }

        private void port_DataReceived(object sender,
          SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
            AppendText(port.ReadExisting());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now I am getting {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}

Comment: Inner Exception : Object reference not set to an instance of an object